# Upload only newer files to Google Storage programmatically

Tags: google-cloud-platform, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, blob, gsutil

How can I only upload newer files - either with different mtime or size - to a Google Storage bucket programmatically (without using gsutil)?

I'm looking for essentially [the same as `gsutil rsync`,](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) but programmatically.

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) provides a programmatic way to upload various files as follows:

```py
# Python example
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
```

However I can't find any information on performing this only on newer files.

All answers I found on StackOverflow suggest using `gsutil` which I cannot use in this case.
The [documentation on `blob.upload_from_filename`](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_filename) doesn't seem to provide an answer either - although frankly I don't quite understand what its various parameters do.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to mimic gsutil, you could store the file/object mtime in the objects' custom metadata. After doing this, you could implement the algorithm gsutil uses to detect newer files - it's described at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#change-detection-algorithm .